# Can I keep track of one specific app's sales from someone else's iTunes Connect page?

Tags: itunes, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I'm an iOS developer, and I just found a publisher for my app - they will sell the app with their own iTunes Connect account.

I have my own iTunes Connect account as well, and I'd like to keep track of my app's stats. My publisher says they would give me access to their iTunes Connect page, but I would be able to see their info for all of their other apps. So they suggested to use a service called [Appfigures](http://appfigures.com/).

I'm a bit skeptical - is there really no way I can have access to the stats of **one** specific application in their iTunes Connect page? If not, are there more reliable services to keep track of such data?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't just associate your Apple ID with both projects so you can access the sales data directly?

Comment: @bmike: Because then I would be able to see the sales data of all their other applications, but they don't want that. I should be able to see uniquely the data of one application (mine).

Comment: That's a good reason. Making an Apple ID for each app is a lot of work, but in the end, you'll either have to trust your publisher to report things properly to you or you'll have to make sure you can see Apple's view of the sales.

Comment: AppFigures looks like a great solution to the hostage crisis

Answer (score 3):

They are correct, a user on iTunes Connect has access to all apps, [no matter what their role](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/7_ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html). Obviously this is a terrible design, but Apple has never been too quick to fix design flaws in iTunes Connect.

As you mentioned appFigures has the ability to [restrict a sub-user's access to individual apps](http://appfigures.com/features/glance). The publisher will have to set up the primary account.

I can't find official information from any of the other analytics providers that they have this capability. My App Annie account definitely does not.

Answer (score 2):

### Ultimately, no.

iTunes Connect doesn't allow for that kind of split-reporting stuff.

#### But...

During WWDC 13 a new feature was announced for iTunes Connect: app transferring.

If possible, you could have the app transferred to your personal iTC account. I'm not familiar with your particular situation with contracts, revenue splitting, etc., but this *is* one way.

Comment: +1 for the correct answer, you can't do it. But transferring it to another account isn't going to fly with most publishers.

Comment: Yes, but it's the best solution ATM.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to request a financial authority to download the payments report, and then use an App to view the report. There is an App called **ReportX** can view the details of your App sales and provides tables and charts to sort and compare.

[image]

https://itunes.apple.com/app/reportx/id1328409005?mt=12